# Invalid hlookup result if range lookup true

Tags: excel, graphlookup

I've problem with Microsoft Excel HLOOKUP function as below

[image: Problem]

As you can see, the result is #N/A for function that set true as lookup range

Where I'm expecting is should be 25 since it should find Mangga correctly (Like when it's false)

But searching Semangka would be as expected

[image: Semangka]

Is there something that I miss?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Your first formula working fine. Why you are using `Approximate` match?

Comment: With true the dat must be sorted in abc order.

Comment: @Harun24HR it's for teaching reason. So I need to test all combination

Comment: @ScottCraner But why the result if I search for Semangka is as expected for those two function, 40. But why Mangga didn't gave me same result

Comment: Because S is after A... put the data in alphabetical order and test again.

Comment: @SolarMike But there's Nama toko, which is started with N, in the front. Why searching for Semangka didn't effected

Comment: But... have you tested it?

Comment: @SolarMike of course, question is updated

Comment: No, you have not put the data alphabetical as @ScottCraner suggested.

Comment: @SolarMike so the Nama toko, which is started with N, in the front are excused by the formula?

Or it's just: The unsorted data, makes the result unpredicted?

Comment: If you are going to teach this then you should put in the effort of testing hlookup(), vlookup() and xlookup() as well as the use of index() with match() as they all have different benefits. And you should test the effects of re-sorting your data.

Comment: @SolarMike yes, I'm fully aware of that. But, I expect my students will ask me, If we should order our data first, why searching Semangka would be fine but Mangga wouldn't. When there's N (Nama toko) in the front in both searching Semangka and Mangga

Comment: That is what **you** will find out by testing and/or reading the Excel help entry for each function. And, some of us may well have tested it ourselves if you had provided data instead of images...

Answer (score 1):

While `HLOOKUP()` will work with `Exact_Match` you can also use `INDEX/MATCH` like-

```
=INDEX(A2:E5,2,MATCH(A7,A1:E1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I know that, but my question is why my formula didn't worked as I expected

Comment: @AdhiKristianto `Approximate_Match` only works for sorted data. But `XLOOKUP()` works on unsorted data.

Comment: But why searching Semangka will both give me 40 for both true and false. Question is updated

Comment: @AdhiKristianto Why not? You are referencing same row `3` for both formula and same column `Semangka`. `approximate_match` specially works for numeric value. If you want to teach your student about `approximae_match` then use numeric value instead of text.

Comment: so the Nama toko, which is started with N, in the front are excused by the formula? 

Or it's just: The unsorted data, makes the result unpredicted?